# Unit testing with Vue, Typescript and Karma

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, karma-runner

I tried to adapt the [Vue unit testing guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/unit-testing.html), but got stuck at the first hurdle.  `Property 'created' does not exist on type 'VueConstructor<Vue>'`.

Here's my test, just to verify that my component does in fact have a `created` hook:

```
import {assert} from 'chai';
import MyComponent from '../src/components/MyComponent.vue';

it('has a created hook', function() {
    assert.equal(typeof MyComponent.created, 'function');
});
```

Here's my component under test, `MyComponent.vue`:

```
<template>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
export default Vue.extend({
    created() {
        console.log("bye");
    }
});
</script>
```

This test should now pass.  However, I get an error from the Typescript compiler.

```
$ karma start --single-run
15 02 2018 14:06:17.345:INFO [compiler.karma-typescript]: Compiling project using Typescript 2.6.2
15 02 2018 14:06:18.905:ERROR [compiler.karma-typescript]: test/vue_test.ts(5,37): error TS2339: Property 'created' does not exist on type 'VueConstructor<Vue>'.
```

I am using a file `vue-shims.d.ts`, which is as such:

```
declare module "*.vue" {
    import Vue from "vue";
    export default Vue;
}
```

Comment: Can you try `assert.equal(typeof MyComponent().created, 'function');`. `Vue.extend` returns a new constructor and not an object

Comment: @TarunLalwani That gives `Value of type 'VueConstructor<Vue>' is not callable`.  Using `typeof (new MyComponent()).created` gives `Property 'created' does not exist on type 'CombinedVueInstance<Vue, object, object, object, Record<never, any>>'`.

Comment: So it seems you are using `Vue.extend` wrongly here. You need to use it like `Vue.extend ({
 methods: {
     created: () => "created"
  }
}
)`

Answer (score 1):

The default properties declared in the exported component are saved in the `options` property when using `Vue.extend`.

As such, this could test what you want:

```js
expect(MyComponent.options.created).to.exist
```

It's better this way because `options.created` is an object, not a function; and what you want is to test that it exists anyway.

Comment: Any attempt to reference `MyComponent.options` gives the type error `Property 'options' does not exist on type 'VueConstructor<Vue>'`.

Comment: That's interesting, in your test include something like `console.log('MyComponent Properties', Object.getOwnPropertyNames(MyComponent))` to make sure. For that matter, could you include a minimum example of all your code? Check out [minimum, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Including the folder structure.

Comment: Looks like `MyComponent` is undefined in the context of the test, even after being successfully imported.  But importing and using `MyComponent` in the tiny app under test works fine.  I don't really understand how it's possible.  I might have to investigate and come back to this question in a few days, as it looks like it may be a configuration problem rather than a code problem.

Comment: Interesting, if you can include the mcve anyway, maybe I could still get to the bottom of the issue.

Comment: Here's the code, minimized as much as I can.  I'm guessing that `karma-typescript` needs to be configured to run the vue webpack loaders so that imports for vue components can work properly.  But no time to test it now. https://github.com/amoe/mcve-48809244/

Comment: Cool, you  might want to add the link to the question proper too, for anyone else who might want to try to see the issue.

Comment: I resolved the compiler issue, but now I found out that although `options` property does now exist on `MyComponent` at run-time, it still doesn't type-check.  I'm thinking that this is a bug in the Vue type definitions.  On the other hand, `(new MyComponent()).$options.created` *does* type check and work.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to create a function to be used on the component you need to below

export default Vue.extend({
    methods: created => () {
        console.log("bye");
    }
});

And then test it like below

```
it('has a created hook', function() {
    assert.equal(typeof (new MyComponent()).created, 'function');
});
```

If you wanted it as component options then you need to use your original template and use the test as

```
it('has a created hook', function() {
    assert.equal(typeof MyComponent.options.created, 'function');
});
```

Comment: The first one doesn't provide the same semantics, the `created` hook is different from the `created` method.  The second idea is good, but gives me the error `Property 'options' does not exist on type 'VueConstructor<Vue>'`